# Winrt: How is " ref new SurfaceImageSource^ in c++/cx used in c# " referenced counted?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

We have an app which creates SurfaceImageSource^ in c++ via ref new and passes it up to c# through a c++ getter in the class that contains it. That getter is exposed through a c# property and used in c# and xaml bindings.

I have not been able to find anything about how such an object is referenced counted from the c# side. I assume it is since it is created as a ref counted object in c++.

I can obtain the ref count from the c++ side and it is quite higher than expected.

Does anyone know how c# handles such an object?

Thanks

Comment: The existing COM interop support in the CLR takes care of it.  An RCW keeps a single reference count, released when the wrapper is finalized.  Seeing high reference counts is nothing unusual.

Comment: Amazing how much stuff out there goes back to COM underneath the covers.

Comment: I am not sure that this should be tagged as [C++], there might be a more appropriate tag that refers to the Microsoft *thingy* that is close to but not C++

Comment: Agreed. It was auto suggested and I thought of removing. Have done so now.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thank you. You seem to be are saying the high count is normal. But the count still needs to go to zero for the surface to be released I'm guessing. I'm a bit perplexed that the binding causes such a high count - like 7 extra unaccounted for refs - and the removing of the object from the source does not bring it back down. And thanks to your comment I am finding much more info out there on the counting methods. Hoping it will lead to resolution of losing the surfaces. If so I'll post.

Comment: @user49011 Any new info on this? I'm also wondering how C++/CX interop calls handle reference counting. As I retrieve objects, I'm seeing consistently growing memory, so I'm pretty sure the reference counts are not being decremented and the objects never freed.